# Adding css styles to dynamically generated items (jquery , css)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-selectors

I have a problem with styling  dynamically generated items. here is the example of grid items.

[image]

i need to add different classes (styles) to grid rows, in specific sequence. first row is grey, next two rows are blue, next two grey again and so on.
i have no idea how to do that. maybe there are some jquery selectors?

Comment: `table row:nth-child(3) {background: blue}` in your CSS should do that, even for dynamically inserted elements ?

Comment: @adeneo it will select only third block. I don't think `nth-child` will help here

Comment: Nice picture, but what does the html look like?

Comment: you can assign classes when you generate the objects, and then style the classes in css accordingly. since you generate it dynamically, as you say. And yes - with showing us some code - it will be more likely we can have some concrete suggestions =)

Comment: thx for replies. About code.. i'm gonna use asp:repeater control, and generated html code will simply look like this: <div>item1</div><div>item2</div> and etc.

Comment: @Morpheus two nth-childs will, it's two 4th child repeaters offset from each other: `div:nth-child(4n), div:nth-child(4n+1) {background-color:blue;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like

```
var classes = ['grey', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'red'];

var els = $('<div />').text(4).appendTo('#x');

$(els).addClass(function(index, cl){
    return classes[ $(this).index() % classes.length ]
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ekAmw/)